# PLUD Decomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix

    def pldu(self):
        n = len(self.matrix)
        P = [[float(i == j) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
        L = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
        D = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
        U = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
        A = [row[:] for row in self.matrix]

        for i in range(n):
            # Pivoting
            max_row = max(range(i, n), key=lambda r: abs(A[r][i]))
            P[i], P[max_row] = P[max_row], P[i]
            A[i], A[max_row] = A[max_row], A[i]

            # LU Decomposition
            for j in range(i + 1, n):
                factor = A[j][i] / A[i][i]
                L[j][i] = factor
                for k in range(i, n):
                    A[j][k] -= factor * A[i][k]

            # Extracting U and D
            for j in range(i, n):
                U[i][j] = A[i][j] if i != j else 1
                D[i][i] = A[i][i]

        return P, L, D, U


def pldu(M):
    return Matrix(M).pldu()
```

I was writing a PLDU Decomposition code for practice without using any libraries but this isnt working for all cases i dont know exactly which can someone help me. I think I'm just doing a small mistake

One Testcase i found out is this

Original Matrix :

```
[[ 2. -2.]
 [ 4.  4.]]
```

P :

```
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
```

L :

```
[[0.  0. ]
 [0.5 0. ]]
```

D :

```
[[ 4.  0.]
 [ 0. -4.]]
```

U :

```
[[1. 4.]
 [0. 1.]]
```